# Why is it not possible to draw the $\overline{Q_3}$ in the plane

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am trying to prove that $\overline{Q_3}$ is nonplanar. I know that $Q_3$ is planar and I have attempted to use the corollaries derived from Euler's planarity Theorem to show it is nonplanar but it passes (and the corollaries that follow since it contains triangles).

Comment: You may use Kuratowski's theorem (that a graph is planar iff it does not contain subdivisions of $K_5$ of $K_{3,3}$. i.e. find such a subdivision in $\overline{Q_3}$

Comment: What is $\overline{Q_3}$?

Comment: Gerry - The complement of the 3-dimensional hypercybe
Kevin - Thanks mate after playing around with $K_3,_3$ without luck and moving onto $K_5$ I finally got it!

Comment: Let me encourage you to write up what you have figured out, and post it as an answer.